# I feel I am duplicating code too much

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am developing an iOS application in Swift 2.

I am struggling with when to create new classes to handle discrete pieces of functionality.

For example, I have followed this to bring in environment dependent variables: http://appfoundry.be/blog/2014/07/04/Xcode-Env-Configuration/

I can get those variables using:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Configuration", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
url = dict!.objectForKey("envURL") as String
```

But should I do that code once, in a singleton sharedInstance, or should I just write it when required?

Within my Configuration.plist I have a number of different key/value pairs. I need to access the values within multiple ViewControllers, which means I could be writing those three lines in 5 different places. I could write them once for each key/value pair and save the result to a property of a Singleton. That would save lines, but is that the right way of doing it?

Another example is I make the same REST call a few times in different view controllers. Should I write a new class to handle that call and then use that instead?

I think this is due to lack of Object Oriented programming experience, so any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: We can't help you with such general statements. You should provide at least an example of code that's too much duplicated, so we could tell you if there's workarounds, for example (it's just an example). For now the question is too broad.

Comment: Those three lines of code. Within my Configuration.plist I have a number of different key/value pairs. I need to access the values within multiple ViewControllers, which means I could be writing those three lines in 5 different places. I could write them once for each key/value pair and save the result to a property of a Singleton. That would save lines, but is that the right way of doing it?

Comment: Ok, then you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35020494/edit) your question and add this information and some more. If you come with a precise question, you'll get good answers. But with this broad one you'll just get opinions, and the question will probably be closed later by the community.

Comment: OK, thank you for the advice, I have updated my question. It looks like I can't move those three lines into a singleton because I then get the error "Instance member 'path' cannot be used on type ThisSingleton"

Comment: *Add the info to your question, not in comments. :)*

Answer (score 4):

The singleton pattern should not be your first tool for sharing behavior between classes. Singletons have their place but I find them to be heavily overused in iOS applications. Use a singleton when you absolutely must enforce that there is one and only one instance of a class. Avoid using singletons as globals (calling `+shared___`) when you just want several objects to have access to some shared state or behavior.

In this case you have some configuration loading behavior which you do not want to repeat. That's a good instinct. We might start by extracting that behavior into a struct whose responsibility is to provide an interface to your app configuration settings:

```
struct Configuration {
    static func get(key: String) -> String {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Configuration", ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
        return dict!.objectForKey(key) as! String
    }
}
```

Now your controllers can each load different keys by calling a static method:

```
Configuration.get("envURL")
```

If you determine that you need to cache these configuration values you might switch this struct become a class with an instance method and maintain a cache on a `Configuration` instance. Each controller could then create it's own instance of `Configuration`. If you need to share a common `Configuration` you might create one and pass it to each of your view controllers when you create them.

Similarly for your REST network calls. You could create a class or struct which provides an interface for interacting with this API. Your controllers can then create and work with instances of this class on demand, or be passed an instance if it is necessary for them to share some state.

Comment: Excellent, this looks like great advice. Question, you have -> String returned. How do you handle errors with this (for example, there is no path). Would you have -> String? and then return nil when there's an error?

Comment: @BrianMarsh good question. I ignored error handling here because I don't know enough to make a good judgement call for your app. You could leave the force unwrapping `!`s and I might do that if this config is entirely non-optional, any missing values are a serious programmer error, and I can reliably expect a test failure or other crash in development. I would return nil if config settings are optional and I expect to see nils in production. I would throw if production nils are unexpected but possible and the app needs to try to recover somehow.

Comment: thank you. This is entirely non-optional so I will force unwraps. This does answer my question. I think I read somewhere about when thinking what type to use, go: enums -> structs -> classes and see which meets your requirements.

Comment: sorry just one more question. For the REST network calls, if I write a class or struct which provides this interface, should the data be stored as part of the class, or should it just be returned and then the controller saves it to a model?

Comment: @BrianMarsh no single right answer. I usually build a "service" or "repository" class which returns model instances. If loading models from some local data store these might be able to be stateless structs. When loading models from network connections I usually end up with  classes (which manage request queues, de-duplication of requests, and caches) a single instance of which is injected as a dependency in to many controllers (e.g.so two controllers making some `getUser` call only perform a single network request).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly related to that specific example, but if you're having issues reusing code, you may want to look into Swift Extensions.  They are a great way to extend the functionality of an existing class or protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

For instance, if you were using a 3rd party library for your restful APIs you could use an extension on the manager to define methods that take the specific params needed for the various endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

> But should I do that code once, in a singleton sharedInstance, or should I just write it when required?

if you find you are reusing that same piece of code many times in the same class pull it out into a separate, private "helper" method.  if you are using it across several classes, You can write a utility class or classes which contain common utilities.  Many people call this kind of class / package a "commons"

> Another example is I make the same REST call a few times in different view controllers. Should I write a new class to handle that call and then use that instead?

when dealing with REST interfaces I like to make client classes to interact with them.  Write one class that makes all the different calls you want to make to a particular REST API.  Each call could be represented by a different method which takes all the arguments and parameters you want to pass to the API. That method should then deserialize and return the value it received from the API.